# How to get spring security context in reactive webflux

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-security, oauth-2.0, spring-webflux

I have a problem with my spring boot application (version 2.6.3).
I have configured reactive spring security like there:

**MyApplication.java:**

```
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableWebFlux
@EnableWebFluxSecurity
@EnableReactiveMethodSecurity
public class MyApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(MyApplication.class);
    }

    @Bean
    public SecurityWebFilterChain springSecurityFilterChain(final ServerHttpSecurity http, final ReactiveOpaqueTokenIntrospector reactiveOpaqueTokenIntrospector) {
        return http.authorizeExchange()
                .anyExchange().authenticated()
                .and()
                .httpBasic().disable()
                .cors().and()
                .logout().disable()
                .formLogin().disable()
                .oauth2ResourceServer()
                .opaqueToken()
                .introspector(reactiveOpaqueTokenIntrospector)
                .and().and()
                .csrf()
                .disable()
                .build();
    }
    
}
```

And this is my web resource (controller):

**MyWebResource.java:**

```
@RestController
public class MyWebResource implements MyWebResourceApi {

    
    @PreAuthorize("hasRole('ROLE_USER')")
    @Override
    public Mono<String> details(String userId, ServerWebExchange exchange) {
        return exchange.getPrincipal().map(Principal::getName);
    }
}
```

It's work fine, when my access token is expired or incorrect the request should be denied. However when PreAuthorized allow request, my user principal will be never resolved in my exchange...

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 7):

In reactive application authentication information is stored in the Reactive flow and accessible from `Mono`/`Flux`. You could use [`ReactiveSecurityContextHolder`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/reference/reactive/authorization/method.html) to obtain the currently authenticated principal, or an authentication request token.

```
@PreAuthorize("hasRole('ROLE_USER')")
public Mono<String> details() {
        return ReactiveSecurityContextHolder.getContext()
                .map(ctx -> ((Principal) ctx.getAuthentication().getPrincipal()).getName());
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

I found this answer looking for a way to add the access token to my webclient requests. If we are using OAuth2 or OpenID Connect and want to access the token instead of the principal's name, then this is not possible via the principal in the security context.

Instead we need to create a `ServerOAuth2AuthorizedClientExchangeFilterFunction` and register it as a filter function to the WebClient:

```
ServerOAuth2AuthorizedClientExchangeFilterFunction oauth =
    new ServerOAuth2AuthorizedClientExchangeFilterFunction(
        clientRegistrations,
        authorizedClients);

        oauth.setDefaultOAuth2AuthorizedClient(true);
```

where `clientRegistrations` is an injectabile bean of type `ReactiveClientRegistrationRepository` and `authorizedClients` is an injectable bean of type `ServerOAuth2AuthorizedClientRepository`.

We can then use the `filters` method for the builder to add our filter function to the `exchangeFilterFunctions`:

```
WebClient.builder()
         .filters(exchangeFilterFunctions -> {
                    exchangeFilterFunctions.add(oauth);
                  })
         .build();
```

Baeldung has a nice background article about this, which explains it in more detail: https://www.baeldung.com/spring-webclient-oauth2