# Extracting Principal data using ReactiveSecurityContextHolder

Tags: java, spring, spring-webflux, spring-security-oauth2, reactor

I have a Spring webflux microservice, with working OAuth authentication in place.
I can access the Principal using the @AuthenticationPrincipal annotation in the controller method parameters:

```
@GetMapping("/user-info")
public @ResponseBody User getUserInfo(@AuthenticationPrincipal Principal principal) {
    return service.getMe(principal);
}
```

This works fine.

But what I want, is to access the Principal directly, using ReactiveSecurityContextHolder, using something like:

```
@Override
public Principal getLoggedUser() {
    Mono<Principal> authentication=
        ReactiveSecurityContextHolder.getContext().filter(context -> 
                Objects.nonNull(context.getAuthentication()))
            .map(context -> context.getAuthentication().getPrincipal())
            .cast(Principal.class);
    return authentication.share().block();
}
```

I need to block, because I need some Principal data to access a non reactive database, loading the corresponding User.

For some reason, the above snippet always returns null. I tried with

```
return authentication.toFuture().get();
```

and got the same result.

Comment: You should NEVER block in a reactive application as it will hurt you performance a lot, im talking serious performance loss, 15-25% depending on hardware and other factors. If you need to call a blocking database you should place the call on a seperate scheduler, as explained in the reactor documentation.

Comment: Also the null check is not needed as null is forbidden inside reactive flows, it will never return null. either it executes the filter function or it doesnt.

Comment: @Toerktumlare "as explained in the reactor documentation" can you please provide a link? I can't find it. Anyway authentication.share().block() should do that... but it doesn't work.

Comment: https://projectreactor.io/docs/core/release/reference/#faq.wrap-blocking

Comment: @Toerktumlare i know where it is... but I can't find a single working example of Principal extraction from the ReactiveSecurityContextHolder. I tried to publish it on another thread sheduler, or to schedule it using Schedulers.immediate(), but the principal remains null.

Comment: @Toerktumlare I add this: if I publish Mono<Principal> directly, returning it in a GET from the controller, it works; but I need to extract other data from the database and to return them as a User instance. So I need to block and extract the username from the principal, call the mapper with the username as input parameter, and return that result to the user. For now I will use the AuthenticationPrincipal annotation, that works...

Comment: @CptWasp please check the answer to a similar question  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71537058/reactive-spring-security-context/71541008#71541008

Comment: @Alex thank you, but there no synchronous access to db or block is needed... I need to use imperative code

Comment: @CptWasp if flow is not reactive why are you using `ReactiveSecurityContextHolder` that is available as a part of the Webflux flow only. Try to use `SecurityContextHolder. getContext(). getAuthentication(). getPrincipal()` that is non-reactive implementation