# Access Security Context inside a Project Reactor Operator

Tags: java, spring-security, project-reactor

I am currently in the process of creating a service which processes requests with the [Project Reactor](https://projectreactor.io/) library.
To communicate with external services, each requests to the main service contains a [JSON Web Token](https://jwt.io/), which it needs to add to any request made to external services.
To facilitate this, there exists a `service-client` library, which retrieves the token from
the `SecurityContext` on each request, and adds it to the request.

What I am now struggling with is how to transfer the security context from the point of entry (the endpoint of the main service) to the point of exit (the `service-client` request), as the security context does not get transferred automatically between operators.

I have already included the [Context Propagation](https://micrometer.io/docs/contextPropagation) library into the service, as proposed [here](https://micrometer.io/docs/contextPropagation), but it does not seem to capture the security context.
I also found a [blog post](https://domenicosibilio.medium.com/the-good-the-bad-and-the-ugly-of-propagating-data-through-reactive-streams-62beac48789e), which mentions the following:

> [..] the Spring Security authentication context is retrieved from the Project Reactor’s context since the latter is already filled with it by the Spring WebFlux Security module.

This sounds like what I am looking for, but I have not been able to replicate this so far, although I include both `spring-boot-starter-webflux` and `spring-boot-starter-security` into the project.

As a short sketch, this is what I am attempting to do:

```java
public void handleRequest(Request request) {
    SecurityContextHolder.getContext().setAuthentication(new BearerTokenAuthenticationToken(request.authorization()));
    Mono.just(request)
      .onNext(request -> {
        return Mono.deferContextual(contextView -> {
            contextView.stream().forEach(objectObjectEntry -> log.info("Key: {}, Value: {}", objectObjectEntry.getKey(), objectObjectEntry.getValue()));  //here I would like to see the authorization set above
            Authentication auth = SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication(); // Seeing the authentication object set above here is the goal, so that I can access it in the library.
            return acknowledger.acknowledge();
          })
      })
      .contextCapture()
      .subscribe()
}
```

Does someone know how to solve this?

Comment: Which `SecurityContextHolder` are you using? As there is a regular one and a reactive one, I suspect you are using the regular one and not the reactive version.

Comment: When writin
```java
return ReactiveSecurityContextHolder.getContext()
              .doOnNext(securityContext -> log.info("SC: {}", securityContext.getAuthentication()))
```
in the operation listed above, the operation times out strangely.

Comment: That is the one you should use.

Comment: Thank you!
Another thing I noticed:
`.contextCapture()` is only available from `reactor-core` 3.5.0 on, while the one supplied with `spring-boot-starter-webflux` before spring boot 3 is 3.4.x.
If you include `reactor-core` > `3.5.0` manually, the system stops working, as `ReactiveSecurityContextHolder.getContext()` calls a function removed in `3.5.x`

Comment: Version of webflux are tied to a range of versions of Project Reactor (or maybe even a single version). So if you are on a previous version YMMV or you might need a different way.

Comment: `onNext` is so-called side effect operator that is sync and reactive flow will not be resolved.  Also,  not sure why you constructing flow like this and subscribing explicitly. Just return `Mono` and webflux will subscribe to it behind the scene https://stackoverflow.com/a/71541008/9068895