# Mono does not emit value when subscribed

Tags: java, spring-security, spring-webflux

I am trying to validate authentication in reactive spring application with Spring Security. I could not read content from Mono in the controller. It is not emitting any values when I subscribed. I have the following code in the controller:

```
@Controller
public class TestConroller {

 public void test(){
   Mono<Authentication> monoAuth=ReactiveSecurityContextHolder.getContext().map(SecurityContext::getAuthentication);
   monoAuth.subscribe(authentication->validate(authentication) 
 }
 private void validate(Authentication authentication){
   System.out.println(authentication.getPrincipal().getName());
 }
}
```

The validate method is never called

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to get spring security context in reactive webflux](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71537058/how-to-get-spring-security-context-in-reactive-webflux). `subscribe` is not synchronous operation and your request ends before subscription happen. Instead of subscribing explicitly - return `Mono` from your controller

Comment: My actual requirement is access Authentication object and perform validation on the principal  it contains.  I am struggling to access Authentication.  I thought I can read Authentication through subscription approach but it was not helpful for the reasons you specified.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although *"nothing happens until you subscribe"*, you don't need to call `subscribe` explicitly. WebFlux will subscribe behind the scene if you return `Mono<T>`. You just need to build a flow combining different reactive operators.

```
public Mono<String> test() {
        return ReactiveSecurityContextHolder.getContext()
                .map(ctx -> validate(ctx.getAuthentication()));
    }
    
    private String validate(Authentication authentication){
        String name = ((Principal) authentication.getPrincipal()).getName();

        // validate
        return name;
    }
```